# Partial derivates of smooth functions defined on a manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, derivatives, problem-solving, smooth-manifolds

Let $M$ be a manifold and $f:M\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a smooth map. Given a chart $(\mathbb{U},\phi=(x^1,x^2,\ldots,x^n))$ on $p\in M$, I define $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x^k}|_p:=\dfrac{\partial (f\circ \phi^{-1} )}{\partial r^k}\vert_{\phi(p)}$, where $(r^1,r^2,\ldots,r^n)$ are the standard coordinates of $\mathbb{R}^n$. I think that the value of the derivate at $p$ is indipendent from the choice of the chart $(\mathbb{U},\phi)$. How I can prove this assertion, if it is true?

Comment: Can you explicite this strategy?

Comment: I don't think I quite understand what you're asking. The very _definition_ of the operator $\partial/\partial x^k|_p$ depends on the choice of chart. If you choose a different chart $(\mathbb V, \psi = (y^1,\dots,y^n))$ whose domain contains $p$, there is no reason why the operators $\partial/\partial x^k|_p$ and $\partial/\partial y^k|_p$ should be equal.

Comment: you are right, @JackLee, my bad!

Comment: @JackLee, what I imagine he is confusing is that the notion of differentiability does not depend on the coice of chart, but the value of its derivative certainly depends on the chart.

Comment: I think that this is a counterxample: I consider on $\mathbb{R}$ the charts $ (\mathbb{R},1_\mathbb{R}=t)$ and $(\mathbb{R},\psi)$ where $\psi(x)=2x$. I assume that the function $f$ (of the question) is the identity on $\mathbb{R}$. Then $\partial f/\partial t|_1=0\neq \partial f/\partial\psi|_1=1/2$ . Is it correct ?

Comment: I imagine, correct me if I am wrong, that what is dealing here is the notion of germ. If two charts coincide at the point, then the derivatives has the same value for the two charts.

Comment: @VincenzoZaccaro: Yes, exactly.

Comment: @frusciante14: No, it's not enough for the charts to coincide at one point. Because the transformation law for coordinate derivatives involves the Jacobian of the transition functions, you need the first derivatives of the coordinate functions to match at $p$ also.